# Какая структура данных оптимальнее для вставки, удаления и доступа к элементу?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, оптимизация, структуры-данных, сборщик-мусора

Нужно выбрать структуру, которая лучше всего подходит под задачи: добавления, удаления и доступа к элементу. А еще нужна возможность быстро перебрать все ключи структуры без генерации мусора.
Так же структура должна содержать одно поле (key), то есть поле значения (value) не нужно.

[Здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/) нашел информацию по структурам данных.

Похоже что ***SortedSet*** лучше всего подходит для этого, но я не уверен.
Подскажите наилучшую структуру данных для поставленой задачи.

Comment: Обычный список чем не подходит?

Comment: HashSet опять же. Могут ли повторяться элементы? И какой именно вид доступа нужен - по индексу, узнать есть ли элемент в коллекции, ещё какой-то?

Comment: List вроде подходит, но может есть что-то быстрее. Желательно чтобы доступ был по ключу (ключ - не индекс). Элементы повторяться не могут.

Comment: Ну тогда обычный HashSet чем не понравился?

Comment: Да я в документации на MSDN не могу разобраться. Глупый вопрос, HashSet не требует O(n) операций на подсчет количества элементов?

Comment: [Retrieving the value of this property is an O(1) operation.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.count?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1_Count)

Comment: А если бы доступ нужен был бы по индексту (остальные условия те же), то что бы посоветовали?

Comment: Я ваши условия не понимаю. У вас там что то про ключи и мусор - это мне ни о чем не говорит вообще.  Если вы более понятным языком опишете требования, я бы мог что то подумать (но уже утром, у меня ночь сейчас)

Comment: С точки зрения асимптотики доступа, включения и исключения лучше всего `HashSet<T>` по идее.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предположу, что вам лучше всего подходит `HashSet<T>`.

Согласно [приведённой вами ссылке](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/#algorithmic-complexity-of-collections), доступ к элементу (то есть по сути проверка нахождения в коллекции по самому элементу) и добавление имеют (амортизированную) асимптотическую сложность O(1). Удаление, согласно [официальной документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.remove?view=net-5.0#remarks), также имеет сложность O(1).

С перечислением несколько сложнее, в документации гарантий я не нашёл, но глядя в [исходник](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/HashSet.cs,f11f1162afd3977a), цикл `foreach` по `HashSet<T>` внутри делает просто цикл по внутренней коллекции `_entries`, которая содержит по сути все элементы `HashSet<T>`, а также свободное место. Процент свободного места, однако, в текущей реализации может быть большим в случае, если вы добавили много элементов, а потом поудаляли их (`Remove` не меняет размер `_entries`), так что у нас выходит `O(M)`, где `M` — *макмсимальное* количество элементов, которое когда-либо было в данном экземпляре `HashSet<T>`.

---

По сравнению с этим:

- `List<T>`: удаление медленное, т. к. требует сдвига в среднем половины элементов коллекции; поиск элемента по значению также требует просмотра в среднем половины коллекции; добавление (в конец списка) быстрое (амортизированно), энумерация очень быстрая (сравнима с проходом по массивы)
- `SortedSet<T>`: асимптотика доступа и добавления хуже (O(log n)), чем у `HashSet<T>`, т. к. нужен расход на поддержание коллекции в сортированном состоянии
- `Queue<T>` и `Stack<T>` — для ваших целей не отличается от `List<T>`
- `LinkedList<T>` требует также просмотра в среднем половины коллекции для доступа, а вот добавление/удаление и энумерация у него быстрые.

---

Всё это имеет смысл, если ваша коллекция будет иметь большое количество элементов. Для маленьких коллекций часто производительность `List<T>` превосходит производительность сложных коллекций (за счёт более простых, хотя и менее эффективных на больших коллекциях операций). В этом случае имеет смысл просто измерить время, за которое конкретно ваш сценарий использования выполняется на разных типах коллекций.

Comment: Просто добавлю, что скорость работы с hashset также сильно зависит от качества хеш функции. Приведённые значения справедливы, если хеш функция работает за константу и обеспечивает минимум коллизий.

Comment: @tym32167: Ну это да, SortedSet в этом отношении надёжнее. Есил структура данных «своя», то можно надеяться на нормальный hashcode.

Comment: Я видел, некоторые используют MD5 в качестве хэша. На таких классах это всё, конечно, посыпется.

Comment: Хочу добавить, что есть метод `HashSet<T>.TrimExcess`, который пересоздает внутреннюю коллекцию, тем самым убирая проблему перечисления за `O(max(Count))`. К сожалению его приходиться вызывать вручную.

Comment: @Zergatul: Ага, эта операция, судя по всему, дорогая (полная перестройка HashSet), и они по сути не смогли придумать хорошую эвристику, когда же её вызывать автоматически.